# copy filtered data to new sheet using advanced filter on current region

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that is working fine in another file, but in a similar file it won't work anymore, and I have no clue what the error could be.

```
Sub Voorstel()
' voorstel om door te sturen naar de klant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim r As Range, c As Range, sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Voorstel")
Set r = Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(2, 6)
Set c = r.Offset(, 7).Resize(2, 1)
 
r.Resize(1) = Array(sh.[A11], sh.[B11], sh.[D11], sh.[F11], sh.[H11], sh.[J11])
c.Value = Application.Transpose(Array("TOT", "<>0"))
sh.Range("A11").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter 2, c, r
c.ClearContents

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\Supply Chain Team\07. Analysebestanden Klanten\16. Behoeftebepaling\Proposal\Proposal" & _
        Format(Date, " dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
        
End Sub
```

I get a run-time error 1004 - the extract range has a missing or invalid field name.
Error is in this line : *sh.Range("A11").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter 2, c, r*

I have to admit I didn't write this code myself, I (think) understand most part of it, but I am clueless how to read the code where the error occurs, what's the 2 in advanced filer ?

Can someone help me to get this code working ?

It needs to filter the below table

[image]

I only want to see the lines where there is a quantity below a date.

thanks a lot !

Comment: The `2` represents the XlFilterAction enumeration of `xlFilterCopy`. Conversely, a `1` would be `xlFilterInPlace`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would introduce more descriptive variable names:

```
' Assumption: No other Workbook was open before adding one
Dim shtSource As Worksheet: Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Voorstel")
Dim listRange As Range: Set listRange = shtSource.Range("A11").CurrentRegion
Dim criteriaRange As Range: Set criteriaRange = Application.Workbooks(2).Sheets(1).Range("A1:F2")
Dim copyToRange As Range: Set copyToRange = Application.Workbooks(2).Sheets(1).Range("H1:H2")
listRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange, copyToRange
```

The last line, which causes the error wants to do the following: Use the Advanced Filter to filter the contents of `listRange` according to the criteria in `criteriaRange`, and copy the results to `copyToRange`.

Advanced Filter is a nowadays rarely used function of Excel, here is a picture of its icon on ribbon:
[image]

I did some experimenting with this code.

If you want this to work, you need data around `Voorstel!A11` (`CurrentRegion` expands `A11` to include nearby non-empty cells), which has a header row from `A11` to `J11` (at least `A11,B11,D11,F11,H11,J11` has to be non-empty because these will be copied to the new workbook) that may contain headers referenced in `criteriaRange` (there is only one: "TOT", and the criteria is that it should not equal 0).

If there was no data at all around `A11`, you would get "Run-time error '1004': This command requires at least two rows of source data...".

If there is data around `A11` but some cells of the header (`A11:J11`, more exactly `A11,B11,D11,F11,H11,J11`) are empty, then you will get "Run-time error '1004': The extract range has a missing or invalid field name".

Interestingly, if you have no "TOT" field, you will not get an error message but none of the data is copied. (You can have multiple "TOT" fields.)

As a demonstration, issue the following commands in the Immediate Window before running the function you posted:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Voorstel").Range("A11:J11").Value = "TOT"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Voorstel").Range("A12:J12").Value = 1
```

The expected result is that the new workbook's first sheet's `A1:F1` range will contain "TOT", its `A2:F2` range will contain 1, and no error message will appear.